update office. terminal not working
I'm a novice. I've copied the sudo commands to update/install FreeOffice from the linked website. Then I opened the terminal and pasted the text. I was asked for my password, which I entered. A command line comes up beginning root@.....(name of pc) ~#
What am I doing wrong? Please help, I really want to get the hang of Ubuntu!

What is "the linked website"? One of the commands you entered has likely opened a root shell - see What does a hash sign (#) at the end of the directory path in a Bash prompt mean?.

Open the terminal, and enter these commands to install the latest version of SoftMaker FreeOffice:
cd Desktop/    
wget -c https://www.softmaker.net/down/softmaker-freeoffice-2024_1218-01_amd64.deb  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install -f ./softmaker-freeoffice-2024_1218-01_amd64.deb  

If you already downloaded the SoftMaker FreeOffice .deb file, you can change directories with cd to the directory containing the .deb file that you downloaded, and run the last two commands from there. If you  already downloaded either the SoftMaker FreeOffice .rpm file or the .tgz file, those aren't the right files for Ubuntu (they're too complicated for a new user to install), and you need to download the .deb file instead.

Alternatively you can run the following commands to configure SoftMaker FreeOffice to be updated automatically like the rest of your installed apt packages.
sudo -i
mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
wget -qO- https://shop.softmaker.com/repo/linux-repo-public.key | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/keyrings/softmaker.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/softmaker.gpg] https://shop.softmaker.com/repo/apt stable non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/softmaker.list
apt update
apt install softmaker-freeoffice-2024

